# PHP Register Not Echoing Right Result

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

```
<?php
$server_host = "host";
$server_username = "username";
$server_password = "password";
$server_dbName = "data base name";

$player_username = $_POST ["usernamePost"];
$player_password = $_POST ["passwordPost"];
$player_displayName = $_POST ["displayNamePost"];

$conn = new mysqli ($server_host, $server_username, $server_password, $server_dbName);

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error connecting to the server.";
}

$query_code = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '{$_POST[usernamePost]}'";
$result_login = mysqli_query ($conn,$query_code);
$anything_found = mysqli_num_rows ($result_login);

if ($anything_found > 0) {
echo "An account with this username or display name already exsists, please choose another.";  
}

if ($anything_found <= 0) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Display_Name)
        VALUES ('".$player_username."','".$player_password."','".$player_displayName."')";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "You may now login.";
}
if (!$result) {
        echo "Error.";




        }
}   
?>
```

I'm using the Unity Engine to display the echoed result, does this script seem that it will echo "An account with this username or display name already exsists, please choose another." if there is already a username with the username entered? Also, would it echo "You may now login." if the account was created?

I made this script myself, I'm new to this PHP stuff. I'd appreciate it if someone looked this code over and explained to me why this isn't working.

Comment: This code is so bad :( It's not only because of non existing error handling, sql injection vulnerability but mainly with broken logic and flow. These `if`s begging for `else`, these unnecessary variables, these `echo()` on fatal errors...

Comment: Gotcha. This is my first PHP script, so I'm still learning about security, hashing, and encrypting. What do you mean by "ifs begging for else"?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp and http://php.net/manual/pl/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score -2):

The logic is wrong. Conditional statements are hanging dangerously :-)
Use this

```
<?php
    $server_host = "host";
    $server_username = "username";
    $server_password = "password";
    $server_dbName = "data base name";

    $player_username = $_POST ["usernamePost"];
    $player_password = $_POST ["passwordPost"];
    $player_displayName = $_POST ["displayNamePost"];

    $conn = new mysqli ($server_host, $server_username, $server_password, $server_dbName);

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Error connecting to the server.";
    }

    else{
    $query_code = "SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '{$_POST[usernamePost]}'";
    $result_login = mysqli_query ($conn,$query_code);
    $anything_found = mysqli_num_rows ($result_login);

    if ($anything_found > 0) {
    echo "An account with this username or display name already exsists, please choose another.";  
    }

    elseif ($anything_found <= 0) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Display_Name)
            VALUES ('".$player_username."','".$player_password."','".$player_displayName."')";
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);
    if ($result) {
        echo "You may now login.";
    }
    else{

        echo "Error.";

    }
    } 
    } 


 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, :).

Comment: server_host should be locahost

Also, post the error you are getting and your table structure